# Javascript: Check if there is any space between a string delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to trim out or add a space to any word before or after any slash(/) located within the string.

```
var str = 'some/value    /even /more   /text';

// should ideally be equal to this 'some /value /even / more text'
```

I managed to get this to work using `.split()` and `.join()`

```
var text = $(this).val();
var arr = text.split('/');

for(var i=0, limit = arr.length; i < limit; i++) {
   arr[i] = $.trim(arr[i]);
}

arr.join(' / ');
```

but the I think this could be further optimized with regular expressions.

Comment: I see no logic in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/\s*\/\s*/g, ' / ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like that?

```
var str = this.value.replace(/\s*\/\s*/g, " / ");
```

<s>It can also be done with:</s>

```
var str = this.value.match(/[^ /]+/g).join(" / ");
```

Comment: Your second version fails on `""`, `" "`, and `"/"`.

Comment: @melpomene Agreed. That was a bad try.